# Mandrill is throwing an undefined error

Tags: php, email, mandrill

I'm beginning to try out Mandrill as my php mail solution but have run into a brick wall. I've followed their php tutorial which has resulted in the following code:

```
require_once 'Mandrill.php'; //Not required with Composer

try{
$mandrill = new Mandrill('API KEY IS PLACED');

// *** Storying the content

$emailSubject = $_POST['subject'];
$fromEmail = $_POST['from'];
$groupTo = $_POST['inquiry'];
$personsName = $_POST['name'];
$phoneNumber = $_POST['phone'];
$streetAddress = $_POST['address'];
$comments = $_POST['message'];
$htmlComments = str_replace("\n", '<br />', $comments);

$textContent = "$personsName \n" .
    "$phoneNumber \n" .
    "$streetAddress \n" .
    "comments \n"
;

$htmlContent = "<p><strong>$personsName</strong><p>
        <p>$phoneNumber</p> 
        <p>$streetAddress</p> 
        <p>$htmlComments</p>";

$message = array(
    'headers' => array(
        'Reply-To' => $groupTo 
    ),
    'subject' => $emailSubject,
    'from_name' => $personsName,
    'from_email' => $fromEmail,
    'html' => $htmlContent,
    'text' => $textContent,
    'to' => array(array('email' => 'testing@email.net', 'name' => $personsName))
);

$async = false;
$ip_pool = null;
$send_at = null;

$result = $mandrill->messages->send($message, $async, $ip_pool, $send_at);
print_r($result);
}
catch(Mandrill_Error $e){
// Mandrill errors are thrown as exceptions
    echo 'A mandrill error occurred: ' . get_class($e) . ' - ' . $e->getMessage();
// A mandrill error occurred: Mandrill_Unknown_Subaccount - No subaccount exists with the id 'customer-123'
    throw $e;
}

// Testing Vars
//var_dump($result);die();
```

I am getting an error thanks to the catch, but it is a nondescript error. What it prints out is

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [email] => testing@email.net [status] => sent [_id] => ceb9b2d536824fbaa3c03e38e86035e6 [reject_reason] => ) )
```

The sent [_id] is obviously different every time. I have no idea why it is being rejected. I don't have any errors in my code that I know of. I've tested this locally and live and get the same results each time.

What am I missing?

Comment: it shows `[status] => sent` what am I missing?

Comment: Exactly, it shows status => sent, no reject reason and looks like a `print_r()`, not the exception caught...So basically you're not receiving emails?

Comment: @DamienPirsy - That's what I was thinking as well. OP, did you check your spam folder?

Comment: Nothing in spam, nothing at all. What concerns me is that the reject_reason is present, but empty.

Comment: That's not an error...

Answer (score 0):

Well I feel like a buffoon. The mail was being sent, and was not going to spam. The issue was my mail client. It's not receiving mail.

A trip to the webmail interface, there it is.

Not sure how to mark this one. Should I just delete it? Or does it have value?